# How to calculate MFLOPS using Valgrind knowing execution time?

Tags: c, valgrind

I have a program that multiply three matrix, and I know the execution time. Know I have to calculate MFLOPS of the program, I've been told to use Valgrind but I don't know what to do with de output of Valgrind. Some advice would be great.

**Edit**
I know than valgrind tells the dynamic instructions, but I just need the floting point operation number of instructions. Is this posible?

Comment: valgrind --tool=lackey --detailed-counts=yes gives the nr of AluOps for float operands or integer operands separately. Maybe that is good enough ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need Valgrind, which is a tool for identifying memory errors.

Instead, look up the computational complexity of the algorithm you used here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Computational_complexity

Which estimates the total number of operations performed. Then you divide the total number of operations by the execution time of your program, which gives an answer in floating point operations per second, or just FLOPS. TO get MFLOPS you divide by one million.

Note that depending on exactly what you're trying to measure, you should either just measure the execution time of the code segment you're interested in, or you should measure the whole program execution time, but in either case you should understand what you're doing and why it's appropriate. How to accurately time a program or sections of a program is a separate topic that has already been asked here before.

Comment: valgrind is not a tool to identify memory errors. Valgrind is a framework to build various tools, and *one* of these tools is memcheck, that identify memory errors. The default distribution of valgrind has several tools: memcheck but also race condition detectors (helgrind, drd), and also cpu instruction profilers (callgrind/cachegrind), and some others